# How Do I Get This Solution for an Infinite Summation of the Function ierfc?

Tags: sequences-and-series, boundary-value-problem

I was wondering how this publication gets the following answer for this derivation?

Equation being solved:

$$C_o-C_m(x,t)=\frac{2I_ot^{1/2}}{FAD^{1/2}}\sum^\infty_{n=0}$$
$$\left[\text{ierfc}\frac{2(n+1)L-x}{2(Dt)^{1/2}}+\text{ierfc}\frac{2nL+x}{2(Dt)^{1/2}}\right]$$

Boundary Conditions and Assumptions:

[image: 2].

I thought the function in the summation was the inverse complementary error function ierfc, but I can't seem to get the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ term from its [Integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErfc.html). If I have two ierfc terms, don't I add the infinite summations of both, giving me $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$?

How does the solution change if instead of my original boundary condition $C_m(0,t_0) = 0, x = 0, t = t_0$ it changes to: $C_m(L,t_0) = 0, x = L, t = t_0$?

[Publication](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1149/1.2119795)